Newbie: Best Motor Configuration for Acro Drone
I am very new to the field so apologies for any poor questions. I previously built a 1ft by 1ft drone with 11in props and 1000kv motor with 3s2p LiPo. That obviously cannot do many aerobatics. To make a smaller acrobatic drone, I have two options:

Use 1000kv motor with high pitch, small radius props.
Use new 2300kv motors. The problem is that despite using identical motors and identical ESCs that work just fine on the 1000kv, when I try to spin up all 4 motors, only any two start at random. Sometimes only 1 starts, other times, 3 start. Never all 4. When I arm, the motors that don't spin don't vibrate or make any sounds.

So my question is this, which option should I use and how can I debug and fix the motor issue?

Did you also change the battery when switching to the higher power motors? A 3s2p battery is likely not sufficiently robust to power the new configuration

I tried a 12V 320W switching mode DC power supply.

320W may very well not be high enough to handle power transients from trying to start the motor. I'd recommend going back to a battery

So, do you think my fully charged 3s2p 50C Lipo can handle it, or should I get a better battery? If I need a better battery, what config do you recommend?

That is likely a good starting point. If the issue persists, you might consider getting a more capable battery
